# Using XPath for building hierarchical Menu with recursive elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have a problem with building recursive Menu using `XMLDataSource` in case when I try to use `XPath`. When `XPath=""` then Menu works fine showing Root element and all hierarchy under it. But I need that Menu begins at least from the second level of hierarchy.
XML-schema file contains definitions:

```
<xs:element name="Menu" type="TopMenuType"/>
<xs:element name="MenuItem" type="TopMenuItemType"/>

<xs:complexType name="TopMenuItemType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="TopMenuItemType" name="MenuItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Caption" default=""/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TopMenuType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="TopMenuItemType" name="MenuItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>      
</xs:complexType>
```

And XML-file itself contains data according to this schema:

```
<Menu xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TopMenuData.xsd">
<MenuItem Caption="Profile">
    <MenuItem Caption="Regulatory Transactions"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Caption="Work Management"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Caption="Work Queues"></MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Caption="Message Queues" URL="MQ.aspx">
    <MenuItem Caption="Appointment Queues">
        <MenuItem Caption="Termination Queues"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Caption="Filling Status"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

When I try to assign values to XPath (something like `/Menu`, `//MenuItem`, `/MenuItem`, `/Menu/MenuItem`) then the Menu controls shows in design time `There was an error rendering the control` and doesn't show anything in runtime.

I tried to use attribute `ref` in XSD definition. it did not help me.

What is wrong? Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: The behavior of XPath has nothing to do with your XSD.  Your XML uses a namespace.  Are you sure you don't need to use namespace prefixes in your XPath? `/m:Menu`, `//m:MenuItem`.

Comment: You describe your problem in terms of behavior (things show or don't show at run time), but neither XML nor XSD nor XPath specify behavior; they are all purely declarative.  It may help, then, if you say what environment you are working in and what XPath interpreter is involved.  (That said, JLRishe has almost certainly identified the problem:  your XPath expressions are not matching because they don't refer to elements in the namespace your XML elements are using.)

Answer (score 0):

Real problem of my XML was not in recursion. Recursion works fine. The problem was in namespaces. According to comment of **JLRishe**, adding of namespace is enougn for solwing this problem. (My Menu began work as it should ater assigning **XPath="/*"**). Thanks.